# How can add the lines in this table

Tags: tables, multirow

I don't know why my table doesn't have line between cells and outline

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Expression} & Modality\\
    & Expressive Symbols\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Replication} & Overlaying\\
    & Affixing\\
    & Stacking\\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Narration} & Storyline Foundation\\
    & Block Formation\\
    & Group Composition\\
    & Frame Fixation\\
    \hline
     \multirow{4}{*}{Connection} & Transition\\
    & Progression\\
    & Execution\\
    & Aggregation\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{The Design Rules Structure}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
\end{table}
```

Comment: For the vertical lines, change `\begin{tabular}{cc}` to `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}`. For the horizontal lines, take a look at the `\cline` command.

Comment: Please read https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\cline` to add horizontal lines that go through partial cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{Expression} & Modality \\ \cline{2-2}
      & Expressive Symbols\\
      \hline
      \multirow{3}{*}{Replication} & Overlaying\\ \cline{2-2}
      & Affixing\\ \cline{2-2}
      & Stacking\\ \cline{2-2}
      \hline
      \multirow{4}{*}{Narration} & Storyline Foundation\\
      & Block Formation\\ \cline{2-2}
      & Group Composition\\ \cline{2-2}
      & Frame Fixation\\ \cline{2-2}
      \hline
       \multirow{4}{*}{Connection} & Transition\\ \cline{2-2}
      & Progression\\ \cline{2-2}
      & Execution\\ \cline{2-2}
      & Aggregation\\ \cline{2-2}
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The Design Rules Structure}
  \label{table:DesignPrinciples}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a reminder that if even if you are only spanning a single cell, you still need to specify a beginning and ending cell. Hence `\cline{2-2}` and not `\cline{2}`.

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tabularray` package you can write simpler and shorter code for table, and get a wee bit nicer looking table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={cc}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{} Expression
    & Modality                      \\
    & Expressive Symbols            \\
\SetCell[r=3]{} Replication
    & Overlaying                    \\
    & Affixing                      \\
    & Stacking                      \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} Narration
    & Storyline Foundation          \\
    & Block Formation               \\
    & Group Composition             \\
    & Frame Fixation                \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} Connection          
    & Transition                    \\
    & Progression                   \\
    & Execution                     \\
    & Aggregation                   \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{The Design Rules Structure}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, to my opinion table will looks nicer, if its content will be left aligned:

[image]

For this table you only need to change `colspec` to `colspec = {ll}`.

Comment: Thank you...........

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{Expression}
    & Modality              \\
    & Expressive Symbols    \\
\Block{3-1}{Replication}
    & Overlaying            \\
    & Affixing              \\
    & Stacking              \\
\Block{4-1}{Narration}
    & Storyline Foundation  \\
    & Block Formation       \\
    & Group Composition     \\
    & Frame Fixation        \\
\Block{4-1}{Connection}  
    & Transition            \\
    & Progression           \\
    & Execution             \\
    & Aggregation           \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{The Design Rules Structure}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]